# Vagrant ubuntu 12.04 mail (postfix)

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm working on a VM with vagrant (ubuntu 12.04).

I want to send a mail with PHP : `mail('xxxx@gmail.com', 'test', 'test')`

If I `var_dump` this line, i have `bool(true)`.

I install postfix on my VM : `sudo apt-get install postfix`

But i never receive the email. If i try `sendmail xxxxx@gmail.com` in command line, the same, no error but no email.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This will not answer your question but instead solve your problem: Use PHPMailer instead: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: to add to this, when I assumed I had a similar issue it was that all the emails being sent were going to the spam folder. Make sure you check in there before making any major changes